Windows authentication only works for http://localhost:80
I modified this sample app (https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/servers/httpsys/samples/8.x/SampleApp) such that:
line 14 in Program.cs now reads:
(before): options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.None;
(after): options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;

line 17 in Program.cs now reads:
(before): options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
(after): options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;

line 20 in Program.cs now reads:
(before): options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:5005");
(after): options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:80");

Windows authentication works for localhost and port 80, the sample project builds and runs and the index page renders without prompting for username/password. User.Identity.Name contains the logged in username and the domain to which the user is logged in.
I then proceed to apply the final change:
line 20 in Program.cs now reads:
(before): options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:80");
(after): options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:80");

After applying the changes listed above, the project builds and runs, but the browser presents the built-in login prompt, asking for a username/password.
I have added 2 URL reservation entries and the command "netsh http show urlacl" outputs the following:
Reserved URL            : http://localhost:80/
        User: \Everyone
            Listen: Yes
            Delegate: No
            SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)

Reserved URL            : http://127.0.0.1:80/
        User: \Everyone
            Listen: Yes
            Delegate: No
            SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)

What am I missing? Why does this stop working when I apply the changes above?

I got it to work with the following:

the HTTP.sys demo application should be running on a server joined to an AD domain
the user accessing the URL should be signed on as AD user
the url should be whitelisted, ie. added to Trusted Sites and Local Intranet using the windows Internet Options window

With the above, when accessing the demo url, the user will be automatically signed in.
